# robots.txt and wildcard at the end od disallow

Tags: robots.txt

I need to disallow indexing 2 pages, one of them dynamic:
site.com/news.php
site.com/news.php?id=__
site.com/news-all.php

What should I write in robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *  
Disallow: /news
```

or

```
Disallow: /news*
```

or

```
Disallow: /news.php*  
Disallow: /news-all.php
```

Should one use wildcard in the end or not?

Comment: And if i want disallow  "/page.php?id=N", but not "/page.php" itself, how should i use wildcard?

Comment: I've found  that there is nice tool in google webmaster - "Test robots.txt".  
"Disallow: /news" without any wildcard works fine for everything starting from "news"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Allow and Disallow lines in robots.txt say, "allow (or disallow) anything that starts with".

So:

`Disallow: /news.php`

is the same as

`Disallow: /news.php*`

Provided, of course, that the bot reading robots.txt understands wildcards.  If the bot doesn't understand wildcards, then it will treat the asterisk as a part of the actual file name.

An asterisk at the end of the line is superfluous, and potentially hazardous.

Answer (score 2):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /news.php?id=*

User-agent: *
Disallow: /news-all.php
```

More info [here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449)

**EDIT:**

The first rule will allow news.php with parameters but allow news.php without ?id=__. If you do not want to crawl news.php that you have to use /news.php*

Answer (score 1):

For sure

```
Disallow: /news.php
Disallow: /news-all.php
```

is correct.
No stars are needed if you have the full filename.
It is though interesting for me wheather the

```
Disallow: /news*
```

approach can work.